# Magento 2 don't create Data base tables

Tags: magento2, php, database, datatable

I have 3 weeks trying to install by composer some modules but when i see the data base i cant found any data table of the module. I recibe different issues but always persist this kind of issue:

2 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'DatabaseName.aw_raf_summary' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT `aw_raf_summary`.`id` FROM `aw_raf_summary` WHERE (referral_link = :referral_link) AND (website_id = :website_id)
Exception #1 (PDOException): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'DatabaseName.aw_raf_summary' doesn't exist.

This is an example after of install Refer A Friend (Component name: aheadworks/module-raf Component version: 1.1.3)
I'm using Magento 2 CE 2.3.4

My steps on command line are:

composer require aheadworks/module-raf
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento cache:clean

Comment: go to your database and search the setup_module after check

Comment: Thanks for answer, on my setup_module table i cant found any new module, the installation by composer dont create or update any table.